# Can't scroll Google Maps popup on mobile

Tags: html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a popup that appears when the user clicks on a marker on the map (I'm using Google Maps JavaScript API).

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="popup" class="popup-bubble-content">
    ... content inside
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup-bubble-content {
    z-index: 1000000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var popupList = document.getElementById('popup');
... some processing code
popup = new Popup(latLng, popupList);
popup.setMap(map);
```

On mobile, you can click the content inside the popup, but you can't **touch scroll**.  Scrolling works fine on PCs with a trackpad or mouse, but touch scroll is not working.

I have tried...

- Setting a height on the div
- Setting z-index to a high number
- Setting overflow-y to scroll/auto;
- Adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
- Setting position: fixed

None of these have worked for me.

Here is a [picture](https://i.gyazo.com/f976bae655c85a0c57768fdc7f82f84b.png) of what the popup looks like.  The scroll bar is visible, but touch scroll is not working.

EDIT:

I made a slight discovery.  If I append the popup to say, the `body` element after it is created, it works fine, but it is not positioned correctly.  The touch scroll problem was caused by `popup.setMap(map)`, after which the popup became a MVCObject and became the child of some random element created by the Google Maps API.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, or at least an unintended feature.  I am submitting a bug report.

Comment: You have not provided enough Javascript code. I've just looked at the official example and it works fine. Could you please add whole the map and popup initialization function to the question?

Comment: Can you please post the code or Fiddle url.

Comment: The two finger scroll to tell the map to scroll and not the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've seen this before when embedding a forum, I would try changing `overflow-y: auto;` to `overflow-y: touch;` and make sure that you choose a content width and height and repeat them throughout.